# ASP.NET App Performance due to too many exceptions

Tags: asp.net, exception

I am doing load testing for my Application, I am running 250 virtual users to access my website.I am using  HP Load Runner.

After 40 minutes of load testing, I checked # of Exceptions thrown counter, it is 11000 exceptions.

How bad is that? what is the recommended fix?

Comment: It's bad. Write unit tests!!!

Comment: What type of exceptions are we talking about? ASP.NET throws ThreadAbortExceptions to clean up resources used by worker threads after each request, so this could be very bad or it could be completely normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be throwing so many exceptions. Check if these are exceptions like NullReference , ArrayOutOfBounds, ArgumentException etc. These must never occur in your code.
Try to categorize the type of exceptions that are coming and from where they are coming.
Read this wonderful article by Jon Skeet on how costly exceptions are in .Net: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/5250/exceptions-and-performance-in-net/

Answer (score 0):

Look for the most frequent exception type or location of the most `throw new exception` and code safe guards to avoid throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should not allow that many exceptions in your code that is a huge performance hit.  Suggest catching the simpler one earlier and avoiding them with the appropriate checks.   No one deserves to see in an 'Object Reference not set to an instance of an object', not even YOUR listener.